Multiple monitors unavailable after install of 6.5.0.27 kernel
My secondary monitor no longer works after update from 6.5.0.26 to 6.5.0.27 kernel.
Its on the HDMI port.
I booted into Windows and the monitor works fine.  Booted into 6.5.0.26 monitor works fine.
I did notice there is not a corresponding Nvidia module for 6.5.0.27, newest listed is linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.5.0-26-generic
I have reverted to using 6.5.0.26 for the time being.

Did you mean linux-modules-6.5.0-26-generic? There should be an equivalent "27" package installed. What does ubuntu-drivers list show?  Add requested info to your original posting.  The Software & Updates program/Additional Drivers tab should show what's running and what's available so you can easily switch.

Ubuntu released a new kernel, 6.5.0.28!
I have been using 6.5.0.26 since 6.5.0.27 broke the Nvidia driver.
6.5.0.28 is working fine, I watched the kernel install and could see the Nvidia build and installation succeed.
Rebooted and dual monitors are back!
Scott
